# Inserting a div right under another one

Tags: html

This is what im trying to make:

[image: 1]

I only have a simple problem, ive completed the first half of it, with the big 1920x754 picture but then i cant seem to insert a div under it no matter what,it just goes somewhere else, maybe something is wrong with my code, but i find it hard to tell.

```css
#Header {
    height: 65px;
    width: 1920px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#Menu {
    height: 54px;
    width: 1920px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    border-right: 3px solid #030303;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    padding-right: 545px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    padding-left: 42px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#Building {
    background-image: url(Mintakep1.jpg);
    height: 754px;
    width: 1920px;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;

}


body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}

#Block {
    height: 454px;
    width: 620px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0.8);
    margin-left: 657px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header"><img src="MoMA.png" width="264" height="65" alt="" /></div>
<div id="Menu">
    <div class="box">Home</div>
    <div class="box">Booking</div>
    <div class="box">Gallery</div>

</div>

<div id="Building">
    <div id="Block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can't insert new `<div>` into your code, I guess need a `row` for new `<div>`. In Bootstrap CSS, you need a `<div class="row">` and then add a column with `<div class="col-##">`. You can grab a Bootstrap CSS for your reference to add new `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. If you want another block as the first one, you need to duplicates the corresponding HTML and use `class` instead of `id` (`id` should be unique on a HTML page)

Corresponding code below

```css
#Header {
    height: 65px;
    width: 1920px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#Menu {
    height: 54px;
    width: 1920px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    border-right: 3px solid #030303;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    padding-right: 545px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
    padding-left: 42px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.Building {
    background-image: url(Mintakep1.jpg);
    height: 754px;
    width: 1920px;
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;

}


body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}

.Block {
    height: 454px;
    width: 620px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0.8);
    margin-left: 657px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Header"><img src="MoMA.png" width="264" height="65" alt="" /></div>
<div id="Menu">
    <div class="box">Home</div>
    <div class="box">Booking</div>
    <div class="box">Gallery</div>

</div>

<div class="Building">
    <div class="Block"></div>
</div>
<div class="Building">
    <div class="Block"></div>
</div>
```